# How to import data from excel file and identify subcategory

Tags: php

I am making the function of importing data from the excel file with the following structure

[image: example data]

i want loop the datas of excel then insert to categories table and determined subcategory by value of first column. Eg: 101 is sub category of 1, 101001 is sub of 101,...

I have been thinking for a long time and looking for it but not yet. Hope the helping.

Comment: Should the value for Ruby be 102003 instead of what is shown in the image? Please [edit] the question to include what table inserts you want to occur for the data provided? How deeply nested can the data be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP Spreadsheet https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Reading from a file: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-files/#reading-files

However you parse the cat/subcat, you would want to insert it back into the table with the database ID of the parent.

To determine the parent, start with the first row, and keep it in a parents array.  When you hit the next row, check the parents array if the value exists. You will have to check char by char.  Then add every new category to the parents.  This structure is not really ideal, what happens when PHP becomes a parent, and so on.  PHP should be 10101 at any rate to follow the structure.  Ruby 10102

In all honesty, you don't need second half of the number, only the parent.  Just use the row id.

1, , Programming
2,1,OOP
3,2,PHP

What you are missing here is the row id.  The last part is only the "sort" and can just be removed.  Imagine if the column was a fixed length field which would be "easier" to parse. 3 digit for parent, and 3 digits for the sort.  Start parsing from the top ..

000001 Programming
001001 OOP

What is PHP now? You aren't pointing to 001 (OOP) cause 001 is also Programming.  So adding a row id, you can now point to the id that will be entered into the DB.

1 null 1 Programming  # id parent sort name
2 1 1 OOP
3 2 1 PHP
4 2 1 Ruby
5 1 2 Functional

Comment: I'm using Laravel and maatwebsite/excel. I don't know how to determine which is the parent category.

Comment: Updated - does that help?

Comment: Thanks @jminkler 
I figured out how to do it, thank you for the suggestion.